# Return recordset using a Web Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, asp-classic

How can I go about returning a recordset in C#? These records are retrieved from SQL server. Web services by default uses XML - I don't want this. I want it to return it as a recordset instead. These values will be used by ASP classic.

Comment: What do you mean by RecordSet, like the classic ADO Recordset?  I'm not even sure if that is possible in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return a record set. And none of your .NET types will be compatible with classic ASP. You need to read data from the XML only. Understand the XML schema and use `Microsoft.XMLDOM` to parse the data.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I am new to .NET and webservice so that did help clarify the (non)possibility.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to ingest an ASP.NET WebService in Classic ASP through any other method than parsing the XML response.

The following link has some information on how to take advantage of the MS SOAP Toolkit to make this easier for you: https://web.archive.org/web/20210125161040/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/070302-1.shtml

Comment: @Eduardo, explain, don't just exclaim.

Comment: @John: sorry, just recalled the pain days working with SOAP and feeled the urgent need to exclaim.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a `DataTable` to a ADO Recordset. Here is a link to some code that does that. http://chiragrdarji.blogspot.com/2007/02/converting-dataset-into-recordset.html
I have not tested the code but by the looks of it, it should work.

If you have trouble returning the recordset `com` object from your c# app you can convert the recordset to xml using Recordset.Save and specify adPersistXML
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681501%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

You will then have the xml string representation of a ado recordset that you can return from your c# app to your classic ASP. Your ASP app  should use recordset.Open with the xml as argument to load to recordset.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675544%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

**Edit 1**
Here is the steps you need to take to make this happen.

In the C# web-service

1. Connect to the db and fetch the `DataSet`.
2. Convert the `DataTable` of the `DataSet` to a `Recordset`.
3. Convert the `Recordset` to a xml string.
4. Return the string to the client.

In the client

1. Create the `Recordset` object.
2. Load the `Recordset` with the string returned from the web-service.

Comment: @John Saunders Perhaps my description was a bit unclear. Doing this with a web-service is possible. I have updated my answer. If you still do not think that will work please let me know what the problem is.

Comment: He said, "Web services by default uses XML - I don't want this".

Comment: @John Well. I think that as he does not want to send the DataSet as xml but he wants to send the Recordset. And that can't be done without first converting it to xml. The difference here is that the xml from a recordset can easily be loaded to a recordset on the client where the xml from a dataset is a lot harder to interpret. The requirement of not using xml and still using a webservice does not make sense. You do see the difference of a recordset xml and a dataset xml?

Comment: I think the requirement makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

SOAP web services return XML. That's the only thing they can return. Period.

(for the nitpickers, yes, WCF can create web services that return JSON or binary, but Classic ASP will have less luck with those than with XML).

Comment: you aren't helping.  The person needs a solution not a literal interpretation.  Think outside the box.

Comment: @Dee: the person needs to explain what his problem is with XML. My explanation is meant to be an absolute "stop" to the idea that he can avoid using XML, such that he should stop and think what it is that he really needs.

Answer (score -1):

ado can use xml as a source.

Microsoft OLE DB Simple Provider

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810621

Comment: -1, he said, "Web services by default uses XML - I don't want this"

Comment: You can't change what a web service returns - that's controlled by the web service !!!  You can only manipulate the response from the service.  Treating the XML as a recordset is a good solution.  Don't mark down unless you understand the entire pronblem.